# Mysql : I want to create a trigger which will insert data into user access permission table based on employee table and categories table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have three tables :- category ,employee and user_access_permission . I want to create a trigger that will fire when new category is added , insert values in user_access_permission for each employee id .default value for user_access is 0.

Category table :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category_name` (`category_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Employee table :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_pass` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT=' ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

User Access Permission Table :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_access_permission` (
  `uap_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `section_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `access_level` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uap_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I am writing trigger like this :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_permssion_on_add_category

AFTER INSERT
   ON categories FOR EACH ROW

   insert into user_access_permission(section_id,category_id,employee_id,access_level) select(new.section_id,new.category_id,employee_id,0) from employee
```

But I don't get things right. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
select(new.section_id,new.category_id,employee_id,0) from employee
```

but section_id and category_id come from the category table.

I would suggest changing it to be 'from category' but the problem then is where do you get the employee_id number from?  It's not anywhere in the original insert statement for the category table.  Unless you decide to have it be some default value every time the trigger is fired.